# Yii saves record from form 3 times

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, model

I have the following action in my controller:

```
public function actionEntersales()
{
    $model = new Sales();
    if (!isset($_POST['Sales'])) {
        $model->receipt_date = date("Y-m-d", time());
    }
    if (isset($_POST['Sales'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Sales'];
        if ($model->validate()):
            $model->save();
            $this->redirect(array('company/comissionmanagement'));
        endif;
    }

    $this->render('entersales', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

It should validate and then save the form data, where the "sales_items" have to be saved one by one in another table.

I tried to reach this goal by using a foreach on "features".

This is the related model:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "sales".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'sales':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $company_id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property integer $store_id
 * @property integer $receipt_no
 * @property string $receipt_date
 * @property integer $carrier_id
 * @property integer $activationtype_id
 * @property string $mdn
 * @property string $accountpin
 * @property integer $rateplans_id
 * @property integer $status3_id
 * @property string $created
 * @property string $modified
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Activationtypes $activationtype
 * @property Companies $company
 * @property Rateplans $rateplans
 * @property Stores $store
 * @property Users $user
 * @property Carriers $carrier
 * @property SalesItems[] $salesItems
 */
class Sales extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */

    public $features;

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'sales';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('company_id, user_id, store_id, receipt_no, receipt_date, carrier_id, activationtype_id, serial, mdn, accountpin, rateplans_id, status3_id', 'required'),
            array('company_id, user_id, store_id, receipt_no, carrier_id, activationtype_id, rateplans_id, status3_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('mdn, accountpin', 'length', 'max' => 10),
            array('serial', 'length', 'max' => 18),
            array('modified', 'safe'),
            array('features', 'safe'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, company_id, user_id, store_id, receipt_no, receipt_date, carrier_id, activationtype_id, serial, mdn, accountpin, rateplans_id, status3_id, created, modified', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'activationtype' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Activationtypes', 'activationtype_id'),
            'company' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Companies', 'company_id'),
            'rateplans' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Rateplans', 'rateplans_id'),
            'store' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Stores', 'store_id'),
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
            'carrier' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Carriers', 'carrier_id'),
            'salesItems' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SalesItems', 'sales_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'company_id' => 'Company',
            'user_id' => 'User',
            'store_id' => 'Store',
            'receipt_no' => 'Receipt No',
            'receipt_date' => 'Receipt Date',
            'carrier_id' => 'Carrier',
            'activationtype_id' => 'Activationtype',
            'serial' => ' Serial Number',
            'mdn' => 'Mdn',
            'accountpin' => 'Accountpin',
            'rateplans_id' => 'Rateplans',
            'status3_id' => 'Status3',
            'created' => 'Created',
            'modified' => 'Modified',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
        $criteria->compare('company_id', Yii::app()->user->cid);
        $criteria->compare('user_id', $this->user_id);
        $criteria->compare('store_id', $this->store_id);
        $criteria->compare('receipt_no', $this->receipt_no);
        $criteria->compare('receipt_date', $this->receipt_date, true);
        $criteria->compare('carrier_id', $this->carrier_id);
        $criteria->compare('activationtype_id', $this->activationtype_id);
        $criteria->compare('serial', $this->serial, true);
        $criteria->compare('mdn', $this->mdn, true);
        $criteria->compare('accountpin', $this->accountpin, true);
        $criteria->compare('rateplans_id', $this->rateplans_id);
        $criteria->compare('status3_id', $this->status3_id);
        $criteria->compare('created', $this->created, true);
        $criteria->compare('modified', $this->modified, true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Sales the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function beforeValidate()
    {
        $this->company_id = Yii::app()->user->cid;
        $this->status3_id = 0;
        return parent::beforeValidate();
    }

    public function afterSave()
    {
        if (count($this->features) > 0):
            $sid = $this->id;
            foreach ($this->features as $key => $fid):
                $si = new SalesItems();
                $si->sales_id = $sid;
                $si->feature_id = $fid;
                $si->status2_id = 0;
                $si->save(false);
            endforeach;
        endif;
        return parent::afterSave();
    }
}
```

When i submit the form it save the record 3 times including all the sales_items record 3 times.

I can't see in my code why it's acting like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better if you try to save both tables in the same controller action ... if the values are not input by user it is easier else you will also need to change your form/view accordingly. Once your form is ready you can try something like below (rough code, but you get the idea)...

```
$model = new Sales();
    if (!isset($_POST['Sales'])) {
        $model->receipt_date = date("Y-m-d", time());
    }
    if (isset($_POST['Sales'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Sales'];
        if ($model->validate()):
            if($model->save(false))  
                {
                  if (count($this->features) > 0):
                    $sid = $this->id;
                    foreach ($this->features as $key => $fid):
                        $si = new SalesItems();
                      ........
                      ......

                  }    


    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I switched all to the controller, but it still saved it multiple times.

Comment: The solution finally (in addition to yours) was to remove the "features" attribute from the Sales Model after the save. Why exactely i needed to do that.. no clue, but i works.